# Reference custom object property

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I want to programmatically select an object on the canvas. This object has a custom property: "id". How can I iterate through the objects passing an id (Kenteken) and select the object where id's match? Error: "0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null"

```
function selecteerObject() {
var canvobjects = canvas.getObjects();         
for (var i = 0; i <= canvobjects.length; i++) {
   var idi = canvobjects[i].id;
      if (idi = '<%= Request.QueryString("Kenteken")%>')
           canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item[i]);
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping once too much. Change `for (var i = 0; i <= canvobjects.length; i++) {` to

```
for (var i = 0; i < canvobjects.length; i++) {
//                ^
```